# The right way to LEFT JOIN in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I got some questions in terms of this certain things in left joining.

I have these tables:

dbo.ARoom_type

```
id | roomtype_name |  isactive
---+---------------+-----------
1  | Presidential  |    1
2  |   De Luxe     |    1
```

dbo.AAmenities

```
id | amenities_name | isactive
---+----------------+----------
1  |   Internet     |   1
2  |   Cable TV     |   1
3  |   Bath Tub     |   1
4  |   Air-con      |   1
5  |   Telephone    |   1
```

dbo.AAmenities_details:

```
id | roomtype_id | amenities_id
---+-------------+--------------
1  |      1      |      1
2  |      1      |      2
3  |      1      |      4
4  |      2      |      1
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT
    B.id as 'details_id',
    C.roomtype_name,
    A.amenities_name
FROM 
    AAmenities AS A
LEFT JOIN 
    AAmenities_details AS B ON B.amenities_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN 
    ARoom_type as C ON C.id = B.roomtype_id
```

This is what I get

Result:

```
details_id | roomtype_name  | amenities_name 
-----------+----------------+----------------
    1      |   Presidential |   Internet
    2      |   De Luxe      |   Internet
    3      |   Presidential |   Cable TV
    4      |   NULL         |   Bath Tub
    5      |   Presidential |   Air-con
    6      |   NULL         |   Telephone
```

I can get all the amenities and get all the roomtype names which is what I want BUT I want this to be by roomtype so if Presidential only Presidential and I tried this query

```
  @id INT
  AS
  BEGIN TRY

  SELECT
      B.id AS 'details_id',
      C.roomtype_name,
      A.amenities_name
  FROM
      AAmenities AS A
  LEFT JOIN 
      AAmenities_details AS B ON B.amenities_id = A.id
  LEFT JOIN 
      ARoom_type AS C ON C.id = B.roomtype_id
  WHERE 
      C.id = @id
```

I can only get these results

```
  id  |  roomtype_name  | amenities_name
  ----+-----------------+----------------
   1  |    Presidential |   Internet
   2  |    Presidential |   Cable TV
   4  |    Presidential |   Air-con
```

This is the result, when what I want is it will be like this:

```
  details_id | roomtype_name  | amenities_name 
  -----------+----------------+-----------------
      1      |   Presidential |   Internet
      3      |   Presidential |   Cable TV
      4      |   NULL         |   Bath Tub
      5      |   Presidential |   Air-con
      6      |   NULL         |   Telephone
```

What is the right query when I want the id and still get all the amenities_name even if the value of my roomtype_name is NULL how is LEFT JOIN the answer? Thank you so much

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Tag your rdbms correctly.

Comment: is this `mysql` or `sql server` ?

Comment: oh im sorry its sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You want all data of `AAmenities_details`, then try

```
SELECT
   B.id as 'details_id',
   C.roomtype_name,
   A.amenities_name
 FROM 
 AAmenities_details as B
 LEFT JOIN AAmenities  as A
   on B.amenities_id = A.id
 LEFT JOIN ARoom_type as C
   on C.id = B.roomtype_id
 WHERE B.roomtype_id = @id
```

but i think each `AAmenities_details` must have `AAmenities`
so you could use `INNER JOIN` between `AAmenities_details` and `AAmenities`

```
SELECT
   B.id as 'details_id',
   C.roomtype_name,
   A.amenities_name
 FROM 
 AAmenities_details as B
 INNER JOIN AAmenities  as A
   on B.amenities_id = A.id
 LEFT JOIN ARoom_type as C
   on C.id = B.roomtype_id
 WHERE B.roomtype_id = @id
```

Comment: i just want to still see all the amenities_name even though the roomtype_name is null so if i input an id 1 the result would be:


       'details_id | roomtype_name  | amenities_name 
               1      |   Presidential       |   Internet
               3      |   Presidential       |   Cable TV
               4      |   NULL                 |   Bath Tub
               5      |   Presidential        |   Air-con
               6      |   NULL                 |   Telephone'

Comment: i edited. u should not use `c.id = @id` because it might be null. change to `B.roomtypeid = @id`

Comment: can not the same.

Comment: when `detail_id` = 4 then its `roomtype` = 2, it can not exists on your result.